# substring before and substring after in shell script

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a string:

```
//host:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name
```

I want to fetch value of host & directories in different variables in unix script.
Example :

```
host_name = host
dir_path = /dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Note - String length & no of directories is not fixed.

Could you please help me to fetch these values from string in unix shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bash string operations:

```
str='//host:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name'
host_name=${str%%:*}
host_name=${host_name##*/}
dir_path=${str#*:}
dir_path=${dir_path%/*}
```

Comment: Thanks Putnamhill, this solution is almost working for me. echo ${host_name} host echo ${dir_path} /dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name.
could you please let me know how can I get only directory path without file name. eg : /dir1/dir2/dir3

Comment: Thanks alot for all your help & guidance. I got all three values (host,directory path & file) in this way :
str='//host:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name'
       filename=$(basename $str)
       echo ${filename}
       file_name
       
       host_name=${str%%:*}
       host_name=${host_name##*/}
       echo ${host_name}
       host
       
       dir_path=${str#*:}
       dir_path=${dir_path%%/${filename}*}
       echo ${dir_path}
       /dir1/dir2/dir3

Comment: @Tamanna, I've added one more string operation to remove /file_name (%/* means strip the shortest match of /* from the right end of the string).

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using regular expressions:

```
if [[ $path =~ ^//(.*):(.*)/(.*)$ ]]; then
    host="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    dir_path="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    filename="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
else
    echo "Invalid format" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If you are sure that the format will match, you can do simply

```
[[ $path =~ ^//(.*):(.*)/(.*)$ ]]
host="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
dir_path="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
filename="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

Edit: Since you seem to be using `ksh` rather than `bash` (though `bash` was indicated in the question), the syntax is a bit different:

```
match=(${path/~(E)^\/\/(.*):(.*)\/(.*)$/\1 \2 \3})
host="${match[0]}"
dir_path="${match[1]}"
filename="${match[2]}"
```

This will break if there are spaces in the file name, though. In that case, you can use the more cumbersome

```
host="${path/~(E)^\/\/(.*):(.*)\/(.*)$/\1}"
dir_path="${path/~(E)^\/\/(.*):(.*)\/(.*)$/\2}"
filename="${path/~(E)^\/\/(.*):(.*)\/(.*)$/\3}"
```

Perhaps there are more elegant ways of doing it in `ksh`, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: +1 Nice solution, though this includes `filename` which `OP` doesn't want. Fix would be `[[ $path =~ ^//(.*):(.*)/.*$ ]]` or better.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I can think of is to assign two variables in one statement:

```
$ read host_name dir_path <<< $(echo $string | sed -e 's,^//,,;s,:, ,')
```

Complete script:

```
string="//host:/dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name"
read host_name dir_path <<< $(echo $string | sed -e 's,^//,,;s,:, ,')
echo "host_name = " $host_name
echo "dir_path = " $dir_path
```

Output:

```
host_name:  host
dir_path:  /dir1/dir2/dir3/file_name
```

Comment: I am getting this error :
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `<' is not expected.

Could you please guide me on this.

Comment: @user3379709 it seems like you are using `ksh` instead of `bash`. The question's tags indicate `bash`, so the answers will assume that.

Comment: Interesting solution. I was surprised to see that it works with spaces in the path too (it looked at first glance as if it wouldn't). It doesn't separate out the file name, though.

Comment: Bash assigns the string before the first space to variable 1, and the remaining text, including spaces, to variable 2.